# xpages view picklist custom control

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages, custom-controls, picklist

I am using mark t hughes view picklist custom control from open NTF.

[Link to control on openNTF](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/View%20Picklist%20Custom%20Control/releases/67B2E75C449F30C1862578FC004AB6EC)

I have set all the paramenters etc, however when I load the page with the control on, I get my custom error page, and the error below in my error logging database

> Error on dialog1button5999 null property/event:
>
> 1:
>
> Script interpreter error, line=1, col=35: [ReferenceError]
>   'compositeData' not found
>
> compositeData.picklistButtonClass + " domfindmebutton5999"

This is trying to set the styleClass of a button in the custom control here:

```
<xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.picklistButtonClass + " domfindmebutton5999"}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
```

I am also definately passing this parameter is with the default code:

```
picklistButtonClass="button2"
```

I also followed the video [Here](http://johnjardin.ukuvuma.co.za/2011/10/28/xpages-video-tutorial-how-to-use-the-new-v3-view-picklist-custom-control/) to the letter, and still get exactly the same issue.

Has anyone come across this before or have any pointers as to where I should be looking to resolve it? Im not sure where to start, as all the instructions and video's explain how to complete the custom properties of the control, but there is never any mention of a need to actually modify any code WITHIN the custom control....

Thanks

(as a side note, I am using bootstrap, should this make any difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the theme definition. Look at the Mark Leusink's blog entry here. http://linqed.eu/2014/08/28/xpages-gotcha-modeconcat-in-your-themes/

If a theme has a "concat" definition, that will be computed at a very early phase. To concat values, it needs to compute the initial value. However, in some cases (e.g. Repeat, Custom control, etc.), the initial value cannot be computed at the page-load section.

For such cases, you can override the theme with a special themeId, as Mark suggested.

Comment: Thanks Serdar, I followed the snippet in the link you sent and the page now loads with the control.

I have a few niggles to sort out, but at least I can now load the page, and see what is going on.

Thanks again